# Adding NTFS-Write capability by default

Tags: 11.10, ntfs

In 11.10 the ability to write to NTFS drives was removed. There are ways around this, like ntfs-config, which mounts the selected drives as r/w, but I'm looking for a more permanent solution. I have also tried enabling it in the kernel (when compiling) but that doesn't seem to do anything.

tl:dr I want for NTFS drives (including removable ones) to be mounted r/w instead of r/o (from gnome-shell and nautilus), like in 10.10 and 11.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use NTFS-config and it mounts all me external and internal drives with write capabilities

just run this in commandline after installing ntfs-config

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

this will make ntfs config run and u can enable read write

Comment: But I would like them to be seamlessly mounted through the filemanager as r/w, as I consider ntfs-config (on my computer at least) to be clunky. EDIT: Does the two check boxes effect other mounting, or just drives mounted through NTFS-Config?

Comment: OK, thanks, I retried using NTFS-Config and it does seem to modify the system settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

am posting the fstab entry for ntfs on my system ...

am able to write Ubuntu 11.10 i386 ...

```
# /media/NTFS was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=4E842157842142B7 /media/NTFS     ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46                0       0
```

Comment: Thanks, but fstab only effects drives plugged in at boot, and my machines often stay on long. This is not a good solution for removable drives.

Comment: I use 1TB iOMEGA USB 2.0 Powered Ext HDD having (Samsung disk ) which mounts automatically in Ubuntu 11.10 with read write capability ..has two partition each formatted with NTFS

Comment: I have a 1TB Seagate Freeagent USB 2 powered external drive which also automounted with write capability but from yesterday I cant write to it for some weird reason. Wonder if there is a setting which disables it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. resolved by installing ntfs-config using :

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

then

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

I had a problem of dependencies when I used :

`sudo aptitude install ntfs-config`     Don't use `aptitude` but `apt-get`

- Writing in NTFS partition is not possible unless the package ntfs-3g is installed (this latter was removed in ubuntu 11.10 while keeping ntfsprogs instead)