# NTFS file system has become read only after running Gparted

Tags: 11.10, permissions, ntfs, gparted, read-only

I installed Gparted and all my ntfs file systems have become read-only.I tried the solution given here [How to change permissions to the other drives in a hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk/88087#88087), using pysdm, but I'm unable to change file system from read only. Changing /etc/fstab as indicated in the same post gives me an error. Please help.

Is there any other way of rectifying this problem?

Comment: I found this on the web but I'm not able to comprehend it.[linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/cant-access-partition-after-gparted-install-910798/). Do I have to install ntfs-3g to rectify it?

Comment: will removing gparted help? I don't want to try removing it before I'm sure that things can't be reverted back to normal using gparted.

Comment: make sure you are using `ntfs-3g`, otherwise it might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install NTFS configuration tool and when you open it for first time you will get an option to enable write support on NTFS partitions you have - internal or external.

You can also select which partitions you want to enable support by default.

For example, I have three NTFS partitions - one of which is Windows 7 C: drive and one other is Windows 7 boot loader partition. I enabled write support only for C: drive and not the bootloader by default. Doing this will also auto-mount the partitions for you (by the time Ubuntu boots up). You don't need to mount them each time, if you use this tool.

Go to Software Center and search for NTFS and you will find this one in the list. Just install it and open it, you will understand what to do. I use Gparted too, but I don't think that the problem is with Gparted or something else. NTFS partitions give some trouble sometimes.

Read these for more explanation if the software center doesn't show NTFS tool in its repositories (which I think might be the case with 11.10):

[How do I enable NTFS write support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77655/how-do-i-enable-ntfs-write-support)

[Adding NTFS-Write capability by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74321/adding-ntfs-write-capability-by-default)

Comment: I have 2 ntfs partitions that's working just fine by the method that you suggested. Thanks a lot for that. However, its not working with windows ntfs partition. I get this message 

"Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged". What should I do? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was reading about modifying /etc/fstab. So I tried commenting the lines which related to mounting of windows ntfs partition, and the problem is fixed now. Please tell me whether that will have repercussions on something else.

Comment: @GK: Well, if your Ubuntu is booting properly and if all partitions are working properly, I think there would be no more problems with the partitions. I think you might have read this, but take a look at this question for double check.http://askubuntu.com/questions/120233/cant-mount-ntfs-partition-without-root-access

Also, read a little about /etc/fstab file to make sure you have done things properly. If you come across some problems in future, you will be able to solve them on your own next time if you read about it. Check this out: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

Comment: ForbiddenOverseer, you rock, just like the guy on your display pic :). Thanks a ton!

Comment: @GK: Woah.. spare some praises for yourself too!! TBH, I am also learning here because of you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling GParted. Also, try to remember what you did to NTFS partitions using GParted and reverse those actions if possible. I had a configuration quite similar to yours (11.10, GParted installed, and an NTFS partition auto mounted via `pysdm`). All worked together perfectly.

Comment: I did not make any changes using GParted. I'll see if removing GParted helps. Thank you.

Comment: also (forgot to mention it yesterday) look again at your pysdm settings, for by default it mounts NTFS partitions in RO mode. you need to uncheck that option manually.