# Changing permissions in fstab in order to allow writing in Windows NTFS partition

Tags: 12.04, ntfs, fstab

I have in my /etc/fstab file this line in order to mount my Windows ntfs partition:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1  ntfs rw,noauto,users,permissions 0 2
```

I've changed the owner using `chown` and set the permissions to `777` using `chmod`.

If I make an `ls -lt` it shows the owner and the permissions properly changed.

However I still don't have permissions for writing there, if I execute `mkdir test` it says:

> mkdir: cannot create directory `test': Permission denied

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution, these are the steps I followed:

1. Type `sudo blkid`
2. Get the UUID related to your ntfs partition.
3. Change the `/etc/fstab` file adding this line:

   `UUID="your UUID" /media/"any name" ntfs users,defaults 0 0`

Comment: Have you tried `chown -R username:username /media/sdb1`? That'll give it read write acess.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, the ownership is properly set

Comment: that is rather strange because I didn't need to cchange anything in my fstab. However, I'll take a look and post my fstab here.

Comment: When I connected my external hard drive and checked my `/etc/fstab` I didn't see any entry for my external hard drive. Did you use this HDD in a mac previously? If so, you'll have to turn off journaling. If not, despite the fact that you might get a little frustrated by this answer, check to see if you made any sytanx error in `chown -R username:username /media/sdb1`.

Comment: Do these work? Seems to be a similar problem to what you describe in these 3 links:  [1](http://askubuntu.com/a/74329/41821)       [2](http://askubuntu.com/a/86134/41821)        [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946610)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify owner of the partition using `uid` and `gid` options:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1  ntfs rw,noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,permissions 0 2
```

Note that `uid` and `gid` values are numeric. If you are not the only user of the box you can discover those values by `id` command.

Comment: Is this necessary? I didn't have to add these options to my `fstab`. All I had to do was to `chown` the contents of `/media/myNTFShardrive`

Comment: @drN That is an option, but not a very good one.

Comment: what does `permissions ` do?

Comment: This one worked for me.    UUID=YOUR_UUID      /data   ntfs-3g auto,user,rw,permissions 0 0.