# Permission for backup program

Tags: partitioning, permissions, backup

I'm new to Ubuntu and i have a problem and can't find an answer for it, so:

I'm using Windows + Ubuntu and i'm using a ext4 partition for storing my backup, BUT every time when i need to do some changes on this partition i need to do at as a super user and okay this is not a problem, but when the default backup program need do save the backup there the system is show me and error. Can you help me how to fix that ?

Comment: This is very unclear what you are asking, are you saying, you can run `backup` as root fine but can't save it ? How about some more information, like, Ubuntu version, PC specs, any error messages and a screenshot. You can upload a screenshot too http://imgur.com/ and link it in your question and someone will edit it in top the question. Without the errors, how can we help you ?

Comment: did you use fstab to mount? or how you mount this hdd?

Comment: I'm sorry @markkirby that i didn't write a clear description. Maythux already gave the answer for my problem. I'll try to be more descriptive next time.

Comment: @БогданБогданов Its fine, someone else could understand fine, glad you got sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your external Hdd to fstab so that it's automounted while booting

#### Get the UUID

Run the command:

```
sudo blkid
```

Then open /etc/fsatb:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Now  add the line to the bottom of /etc/fsatb:

```
UUID=UUID /mounting-point ext4 defaults  0      2
```

Replace UUID with result of your UUID of /dev/sdX

Replace /mounting-point with path to mount the partition on

Reaplce ext4 with your partition filesystem type

Comment: @БогданБогданов you are welcome friend

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions in fstab in order to allow writing for this partition, or just change permissions for backup folder

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207180/changing-permissions-in-fstab-in-order-to-allow-writing-in-windows-ntfs-partitio use own filesystm type and user/group settings

Comment: While this may be the correct answer, would be nice to include `how to change fstab` or `how to change folder permissions`. Please see @Maythux answer for good detail and read this on how to write a good answer (you can edit this one) http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer, thanks