# Changing permissions of an NTFS partition for Transmission

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab, transmission

I've been using ubuntu for a few years now, however this is my first time asking a question on the forums so please let me know if I have not provided enough info.

I'm running 14.04 Home on an Intel® Core™ i5 CPU 661 @ 3.33GHz × 4 with 8GB of ram as a media player/server

Currently, I'm trying to get transmission working with the default download directory on an NTFS drive, mounted at /media/paul/Downloads, but keep getting a permissions error within transmission. I have tried chmod & chown, to find out these commands only work on unix filesystems. It's odd, the permissions of the folder `/media/paul/Downloads` is `drwx------` when it is mounted, and `drwxr-xr-x` when it is not.

I have also tried the following:

- Changed the user in the file `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` to root
- Applied the same options in fstab as my other writeable NTFS drives: `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show`
- Tried `rw` option, and `umask=000` in fstab
- Also, tried `rw,noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,permissions` as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207180/changing-permissions-in-fstab-in-order-to-allow-writing-in-windows-ntfs-partitio)
- Several combinations of the last three

This is currently what my fstab file looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=463c5639-f937-46c5-b5a7-67de7b49a999 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c6621b2e-5383-4031-8bd0-1210e0a79147 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/898d19a1-6214-4331-9a53-6318bd104b8e /mnt/898d19a1-6214-4331-9a53-6318bd104b8e auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/EA8CE9698CE930AD /mnt/EA8CE9698CE930AD auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0B181B702141B3B7 /media/paul/Movies auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0E8688030EAF0509 /media/paul/Games auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/89cac2d7-665f-4fc7-ac37-ca4df69c5a3a /media/paul/Television auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/744EFFFF3AFEC7C9 /media/paul/Downloads auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,rw 0 0
```

Where the problem drive is listed last (`uuid=744EFFFF3AFEC7C9`)

Please help me before I throw my computer out of my bedroom window